# Element of a ring acting as a permutation on an ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals, rngs

I am investigating cases when $r \cdot I = I$ for some element $r$ and an ideal $I$ of a commutative ring or rng R.

Clearly, $r \cdot \langle 0 \rangle = \langle 0 \rangle$ for any element $r$ of $R$, and $u \cdot R = R$ for any unit $u$.

Let's call elements that generate the same principal ideal *associates*.
$[r]$ is the equivalence class of *associates* of an element $r$.
Let $M$ be the sum of all ideals $I$ such that $r \cdot I = I$.
$M$ is the maximal ideal with respect to the property.

Obviously, if $r \cdot M = M$, then $[r] \cdot M = M$.
Every element of $[r]$ acts as a permutation on $M$.
Let's check some examples on cyclic rings:

- $R = \mathbb Z_{10}, [r] = [2] = \{2,4,6,8\}, M = 2 \mathbb Z_{10} = \{0,2,4,6,8\}$:
  $2 \cdot M = (2\ 4\ 8\ 6)$
  $4 \cdot M = (6\ 8\ 4\ 2)$
  $6 \cdot M = Id$
  $8 \cdot M = (2\ 8)(4\ 6)$
- $R = \mathbb Z_{10}, [r] = [5] = \{5\}, M = 5 \mathbb Z_{10} = \{0,5\}$:
  $5 \cdot M = Id$
- $R = \mathbb Z_{12}, [r] = [2] = \{2,10\}, M = 4 \mathbb Z_{12} = \{0,4,8\}$:
  $2 \cdot M = (4\ 8)$
  $10 \cdot M = Id$
- $R = \mathbb Z_{12}, [r] = [3] = \{3,9\}, M = 3 \mathbb Z_{12} = \{0,3,6,9\}$:
  $3 \cdot M = (3\ 9)$
  $9 \cdot M = Id$

Questions:
1. Is the set of permutations $[r] \cdot M = M$ aways a group?
2. If $[r] \cdot M = M$, does it mean $[r] \cdot I = I$ for any ideal $I \subseteq M$?
3. If $\langle 0 \rangle \subsetneq M \subsetneq R$ for an element $r$, does it mean $r$ is *irreducible*?
4. Are there any interesting properties of such elements and ideals?

Comment: When you say "unique maximal ideal $M$ such that $r \cdot M = M$, I think you mean "there is a unique ideal $M$ maximal with respect to the property that $r \cdot M = M$. ($M$ cannot be expected to be a maximal ideal in the standard sense of that term.)  I don't think the argument you have given for the existence of the maximal $M$ is adequate (to do a typical Zorn's lemma argument, you need to consider chains of ideals with the property of interest), but I think you can fix that.

Comment: @RobArthan Yes, that is exactly what I meant. As per my argument, I was thinking that the sum of all such ideals would be the maximal ideal in this sense. Is this correct?

Comment: I think it is correct, but you have to show that the property $r.M = M$ is preserved over arbitrary sums (not just finite sums). I don't think that should be problematic. Maybe you could give your question a little overhaul.

Comment: @RobArthan I have updated the question. Does it look better now?

Comment: It looks better. You could make it even better by saying that $M$ is the sum of all ideals $I$ such that $r\cdot I = I$ and is the maximal ideal with this property.

Comment: @RobArthan Done. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**First, some setup.** $M$, as an ideal of $R$, is an $R$-module. Multiplication of $M$ by any element of $R$ (with your property or not) is an endomorphism of $M$ (as an abelian group, because $r(m_1+m_2) = rm_1+rm_2$), and because $R$ is commutative, it's even an $R$-module endomorphism (since $r(r'm) = r'(rm)$). Thus sending $r$ to its multiplication action on $M$ gives us a set map

$$\Phi: R\rightarrow \operatorname{End}_R(M).$$

Furthermore, right-distributivity and associativity in $R$ mean that $\Phi$ is a rng homomorphism, and if $R$ has a unit, it's even a ring homomorphism.

The statement that $r\cdot M = M$ is the statement that $\Phi(r)$ is **surjective** from $M$ to $M$.

**Now, one thing that needs to be cleared up:** If $r\cdot M = M$, it does **not** imply that $r$'s action on $M$ (which I have named $\Phi(r)$) is a permutation. It must be surjective, but it could fail to be injective. Example: let

$$ R = \mathbb{Z}[x,y_1,y_2,y_3,\dots] / (xy_1, y_1-xy_2, y_2-xy_3, \dots),$$

and let $M$ be the ideal generated by the $y$'s, and take $r=x$. Then multiplication by $r=x$ is surjective onto $M$ since $y_i = xy_{i+1}\in x\cdot M$ for all $i$. However, $xy_1=0$, so $r=x$'s action on $M$ has a nontrivial kernel.

*So, in full generality, we need to separate the question about what is implied by the assumption that $r\cdot M = M$, versus the stronger assumption that $r$ acts as a permutation on $M$.*

On the other hand, if $R$ is noetherian, then $r\cdot M=M$ does imply that $r$ acts as a permutation on $M$, which we can see as follows. If $r\cdot M = M$, then $\Phi(r)$ is a surjective $R$-module map from $M$ to itself. In this situation, the first isomorphism theorem tells us that $M \cong M/\ker \Phi(r)$ as $R$-modules. If $r$ acts non-injectively on $M$, i.e., if $\ker \Phi(r)$ is nontrivial, then this isomorphism means $r$ also acts non-injectively on $M/\ker\Phi(r)$, i.e., multiplication by $r$ puts something in $\ker\Phi(r)$ that wasn't already there. In other words, $\ker\Phi(r^2)$ is strictly bigger than $\ker\Phi(r)$. Similar reasoning shows that $\ker\Phi(r^{j+1})$ is strictly bigger than $\ker\Phi(r^j)$, for all $j$. Thus

$$\ker\Phi(r)\subset\ker\Phi(r^2)\subset \dots$$

is a nonterminating, strictly increasing chain of $R$-submodules of $M$. But an $R$-submodule of $M$ is an ideal of $R$, because $M\subset R$, so if $R$ is noetherian, this is impossible.

*So, if you are willing to assume $R$ is noetherian, then we can go ahead and treat "$r\cdot M=M$" and "$r$ acts as a permutation on $M$" as equivalent statements.*

For the remainder of this answer, I will assume the stronger version: that $r$ acts as a permutation on $M$, i.e., that $\Phi(r)$ is bijective. (Your interest is in $M$'s that are maximal with respect to this property.) However, I will *not* assume that $R$ is noetherian.

**Finally, your questions:**

1) For a given $r$ and $M$, does the set of permutations coming from multiplication of $r$'s associates by $M$ necessarily form a group? Answer: no. Let

$$ R = \mathbb{Q}[x;\dots,y_{-2},y_{-1},y_0,y_1,y_2,\dots]/(\dots,y_{-1} - xy_0, y_0 - xy_1, y_1-xy_2,\dots),$$

and let $M$ be the ideal generated by the $y_i$'s. Let $r=x$. Then $r\cdot M=M$ by similar logic as above: every $y_i$ is the image of multiplication of $y_{i+1}$ by $x$. Furthermore, $M$ is maximal with respect to this property: if $M'$ is any ideal properly containing $M$, then $M'$ has nonzero image in $R/M = \mathbb{Q}[x]$, and then this image is a nonzero ideal in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ on which multiplication by $x$ acts surjectively. But this doesn't exist: any nonzero ideal in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ contains a polynomial of minimal degree, and multiplication by $x$ raises the degree, so there is no nonzero ideal in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ on which multiplication by $x$ acts surjectively. So this is an example of $r,M$ that fits your framework.

However, there is no associate of $r=x$, nor any element of $R$ at all, that inverts $x$'s action on $M$. Indeed, e.g., $y_0\in M$, and $xy_0=y_{-1}$, but there is no $r\in R$ such that $ry_{-1} = y_0$.

2) No. In the previous example, take $I$ to be the ideal generated by $y_0,y_{-1},\dots$. Then $r\cdot I$ does not contain $y_0$.

Here's even a noetherian example, which shows that $r\cdot I$ doesn't even have to be contained in $I$: let

$$ R = \mathbb{Q}[t,x,y]/(x-ty, y-tx).$$

Let $M$ be the ideal generated by $x$ and $y$, and let $r=t$. Then $r\cdot M = M$, but within $M$, $I=(x)$ and $J=(y)$ are transposed with each other by $r=t$, not fixed.

3) No. Take the $R$ of the previous (non-noetherian) example and consider $S = R[z,w]/(x-zw)$, and extend $M$ to $S$ (i.e., replace the previous $M$ with the ideal generated by the $y_i$'s in $S$ instead of $R$). (Retain $r=x$.) Then it is still true $M$ is maximal with respect to the property that $r\cdot M = M$, by similar logic: $S/M$ is $\mathbb{Q}[x,z,w]/(x-zw)\cong \mathbb{Q}[z,w]$. This is again a ring in which there is no ideal that is surjected onto itself by multiplication by $x=zw$. However, $r=x=zw$ is definitely not irreducible.

The same type of argument should also work for the noetherian example. Take $S = R[z,w]/(t-zw)$.

4) I don't have a comprehensive answer. (Who decides what's interesting anyway? :) One observation is that if $M$ is nonzero, but finitely generated as an $R$-module (for example, if $R$ is noetherian), then it is not possible for $r$ to lie in the [Jacobson radical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobson_radical) of $R$. (If $M$ is finitely generated and $rM = M$ with $r$ in the Jacobson radical, then $M$ would $=0$ by [Nakayama's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nakayama's_lemma#Statement).) Therefore, there is some maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ with $r\notin \mathfrak{m}$.

Comment: Thank you for such a detail answer. It is slightly above my level of knowledge, but it greatly motivates me to learn all the techniques that are used in the post.

Comment: If you want you can skip all the setup (which is the higher-tech part of the answer) and just read under where it says "Finally, your questions:" In broad strokes it seems to me what's going on is that your conjectures stemmed from the fact that you were looking at these tiny finite rings. In finite situations, injectivity implies surjectivity and vice versa, so that causes a lot of "coincidences." My examples are mostly big rings, where there's a lot more "room to play."